# Overriding @JsonProperty in a nested property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have 2 classes:

```
class Customer { 
   . . .

   @JsonProperty("customer_address")
   private Address address;
}
```

and

```
class Company { 
   . . .

   @JsonProperty("company_address")
   private Address address;
}
```

The structure of the Address object is the same, both for company and customer, but unfortunately my JSON counterpart uses different JSON property names in the two cases, like

```
class Address { // in Customer
   @JsonProperty("customer_city")
   private String city;
}

class Address { // in Company
   @JsonProperty("company_city")
   private String city;
}
```

I'm wondering, but I miss how, if I can "override" the JsonProperty annotation in Address from the enclosing Customer/Company, so to have one only class.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a reasonable effort. Of course, you can write a custom de/serializer and use `JsonSerialize(using = ...)` + `JsonDeserialize(using = ...)`, but it's questionable if duplicating POJO wouldn't be easier...

Comment: Instead of annotating the field, you can annotate getters and setters. Then, those can be overwritten and be given new `@JsonProperty` attributes

Comment: I make [ab]use of lombok and mapstruct, so POJO duplication sounds acceptable, I will pass an extra beer to my code reviewer :) Thank you all!